# Does domain name registrar provide public ip

Tags: dns, webserver

I want to set my own DNS server and web server.I know all setup but I have one confusion during domain name registration from any hosting website does it provide me any public ip or just only register my domain name.
Should I purchase public Ip from Isp to my DNS server and web server ??

Answer (score 0):

> Does domain name registrar provide public IP?

No, a registrar allows you to specify one or more DNS servers that are authoritative for your domain. Some registrars (i.e. [SchlundTech](https://www.schlundtech.com/domains/)) operate their own DNS servers and allow their customers to use them for no or little charge.

You generally get the IP from your server-provider where you rent your server (i.e. [AWS ec2](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/)). If you want to operate your server at home or work, you need to get a static IP from your ISP. You could also go for a solution using DynDNS like [No-IP](https://www.no-ip.com), but that depends on how stable your service is supposed to be.

Comment: Note that many hosting companies also register domains, but the customer has no choice regarding the DNS or webservers. The hosting company always points those to their own servers.